# What does ?? mean?

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking at the code to implement the pageviewcontroller and I don't understand this line of code:

```
let currentIndex: Int = subViewController.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
```

What does `??` mean?

It was used in this context:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex: Int = subViewController.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
    if currentIndex <= 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return subViewController[currentIndex - 1]
}
```

Comment: check Nil-Coalescing Operator 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On its left side there is an expression that evaluates to optional (a value or a nil), on it's right side you provide a default value that is used if the left side is evaluated to nil.

```
let currentIndex: Int = subViewController.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
```

In your example, `subViewController.index(of: viewController)` is the left side that evaluates to optional integer - `Int?`. However, to make sure you won't have to deal with optional value, on the right side you provide a default value '0'. Thanks to that `currentIndex` will always have a value.

If you are familiar with ternary operator, it's intepreted as:

```
let currentIndex: Int = subViewController.index(of: viewController) != nil ? subViewController.index(of: viewController)! : 0
```

Or in `if-else` syntax:

```
let currentIndex: Int
if subViewController.index(of: viewController) != nil {
    currentIndex = subViewController.index(of: viewController)!
} else {
    currentIndex = 0
}
```